# Performing a multi-table inner/left/right join (or correlated subquery) with count?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, business-logic

I'm wondering how exactly to perform a 3-way join using the following structure (much simplified)

```
**Table 1:**
vote.id
vote.item_id

**Table 2:**
item.id
item.owner_id

**Table 3**
owner.id
```

My goal here is very basically to count the number of votes that an 'owner' has. I keep thinking I can simply do this using a correlated subquery, but that seems like it would be a performance hog if votes is huge? Maybe i'm wrong? I just can't get my head around a 3 (or more) table like this. Is it possible to do this in 1 query rather than 2 steps?

ie:

```
SELECT owner.id, 
   (SELECT count(SELECT count(vote.id) as Cnt WHERE vote.item_id = item.id) as ItemCnt
   WHERE item.owner_id = owner.id) as TotalCnt 
WHERE owner.id = :id
```

Would something like this even work? Is there a better, more efficient way to do this?

Any help or advice is very much appreciated as always

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As simple as that:

```
select count(vote.id)
from owner
left join item on (item.owner_id = owner.id)
left join vote on (vote.item_id = item.id)
where owner.id = :id
```

Comment: That's it? Huh. I figured that would be far to easy.